# SSH connection using public/private key authentication fails only for port 22

Tags: terminal, ssh, catalina

I have been struggling for hours to make sense of a specific failure from connecting to an SSH server from one recent macOS system.

```
ssh user@machine -p 22
```

I have added all keys to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the target machine. The keys have been generated with default settings for `ssh-keygen`.

The server is a freshly provisioned Ubuntu 18.04 instance on Azure, we also tried a different cloud provider.

I can successfully connect with public/private key authentication (PKA) from an Ubuntu machine. I can't connect **to port 22** with public/private key authentication (PKA) from the macOS  machine in question.

What am I missing?

#### Symptoms

For connecting from the macOS machine we observe the following symptoms:

- Connection to the server works with password authentication
- Connection to the server does not work with PKA
- When I start a second SSH server using `/usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 2222`, connection to the server works with PKA (using `ssh -p 2222` on the client)
- Same for ports 23, 80
- Same behavior using

  - the built-in SSH client
  - a freshly brewed one (version 8.1p1 with `brew install openssh`)
  - cyberduck

#### Client logs

I checked the logs of `ssh -vvv` for both ports. The only difference (apart from host key differences) are the following lines which are **missing** when using port 22 (this makes it very hard to search for the problem):

```
debug3: put_host_port: [machine]:2222\
...
debug3: put_host_port: [ip-address]:2222\
debug3: put_host_port: [machine]:2222\
...
debug3: receive packet: type 7\
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received\
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>\
```

It appears that, when connecting to port 22, the server fails to send (or the client fails to receive) a "packet of type 7" with `SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO` and `kex_input_ext_info`.

#### Client config

The output of `ssh -G` (which shows the effective configuration) is identical for port 22 and for other ports.

#### Server logs

When looking at the output of `/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd`, the following entry is **missing** for port 22:

```
debug3: send packet: type 7 [preauth]
```

The server doesn't send a "packet type 7"; but perhaps this is just an unrelated symptom?

I also see the following differences:

- Port 22:

  ```
  debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 [preauth]
  debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa [preauth]
  ```
- Port 80:

  ```
  debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c [preauth]
  debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa [preauth]
  ```

  Extra entries (compared to port 22):

  - `KEX algorithms: ext-c-info`
  - `host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com`

  Different order:

  - `ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,`

#### Workaround

For machines that are under my control, I can change the default port of the SSH daemon.

#### Question

What else can I try to narrow down the problem?

Comment: Are the Ubuntu machine and the Mac on the same network? (i.e. could anything on your network, internet connection, or similar be interfering with your traffic)

Comment: Thanks. I don't think this is the problem, because the connection works from the Mac with password authentication.

Comment: @krlmlr Setting this up in my env (Catalina ssh-client > El Capitan ssh-server) this works w/o a problem. Interestingly I don't see any *receive packet: type 7* in my ssh -vvv output....

Comment: @krlmlr I found a related question w/o real answer with a similar problem: **...it turn out that there is a firewall/gateway enforcing the particular policy which only accept Password authentication for Port 22 in the front of the network. It has been applied on the company network which affect easier to reproduce here. It actually work as soon as the policy is taken out and by using the existing configuration.** This doesn't really fit with your finding **...I can successfully connect with public/private key authentication (PKA) from an Ubuntu machine...** but maybe they are in diff. networks

Comment: @krlmlr Even if you think that is not the problem, it is good to ensure that it is not the problem. It is possible for something to block just key-based authentication and not password-based authentication. You might have some "endpoint protection" or whatever installed, if you're using a company laptop - and you might have a network device with "deep packet inspection" or whatever running. If those are interfering with your traffic, it could be the reason for your problem.

Comment: @krlmlr [char limit had struck] *but maybe they are in diff. networks* I meant: the  Mac ssh client (no successful PKA) and the Ubuntu ssh client (successful PKA) are in different networks (or different policies apply) and trying to access the remote Ubuntu ssh server (via PKA) they behave differently.

Comment: @klanomath: This sounds promising, I'll double-check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that you have "something" interfering with your network traffic that is specifically blocking out your attempt to authenticate via keys on port 22.

This "something" could be so called "endpoint protection" software (software firewall), it could be a network device on your network (i.e. router with deep packet inspection, firewall, etc.) or it could be a network device on the network path or at the server end.

This seems to be the most logical conclusion as this can explain why it doesn't work on port 22, but do work on other ports.

I.e. if you hadn't included the port information, I would have looked at the authorized_keys file on the server. It is possible to specify that a specific key can only be used for authentication when connecting from a specific host - or that it must not be used when connecting from a specific host. If you had set that up to allow the Ubuntu host and not the Mac host - that could explain parts of what you're seeing. However, this method does not include matching again the port number - so it cannot explain that.

This is all assuming that you're running the exact same configuration for port 22 and port 2222 (which you stated you are), and that you're running standard OpenSSH software on the server. If you're not, that software might include configuration to discriminate based on ports - but I don't think it is likely.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did try a different network the other day, but it turned out that the connection was still routed via the evil network with deep packet inspection. Also, I wasn't aware that SSH could be DPI-ed, but at the connection stage this does seem feasible. The **other** question I have is why someone would implement such a device.

Comment: I don't know who runs your "evil network", so you haven't given any information we can work with... but one guess is that it is a company network where they check user/password for SSH in a central database/LDAP/RADIUS/whatever at the "firewall" (i.e. network device) in addition to at the actual SSH server. As no passwords are used with key based authenticaction, they could have blocked that to ensure that passwords always are used. Some people do the weirdest things.